# If the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to A$ given by $f(x) = \frac{e^x - e^{-|x|}}{e^x+e^{|x|}}$ is a surjection, find $A$

Tags: functions

> If the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to A$ given by $f(x) = \dfrac{e^x - e^{-|x|}}{e^x+e^{|x|}}$ is a surjection, find $A$.

I know the fact that *"range = co-domain"* but was not able to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Try plotting it. Make a guess. Prove your guess by:

- Showing that $f$ is constant for $x \leq 0$.
- Showing that $f$ is strictly increasing for $x > 0$.
- Computing $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$.